# How can I ask RuntimePermission through list adapters in android using PermissionDispatcher?

Tags: android, android-fragments, runtime-permissions

I am able to acccess Runtime permission from Activity and Fragment but I want SEND_SMS persmission from  a `BaseAdapter` which is in `Fragment`? Is it possible or I have to call it through Fragment `setonItemClickListener` ?

Comment: You can ask from adapter also just you need to ask it by using instance of Application Context

Comment: @Vickyexpert are you saying `getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` to check permissions ??